# Changing html attributes with jQuery

Tags: jquery, character

I am getting a problem with jQuery. I have a page with charset=UTF-8 and in the html-tag I have lang="sv-SE", the page is in swedish.
Inside the page I have a select-tag with some options. The options-tag has a title and the text, ie:

```
<option value="1" title="Blue">Blue</option>
```

The problem is that I have to change the title-attribute and the text, and for that I am using jQuery like this:

```
$('select option[value="1"]').attr("title", "Blå; #2E86C1").text("Blå #2E86C1");
```

but the result is:

```
<option value="1" title="Bl�; #2E86C1">Bl� #2E86C1</option>
```

Why it is happening? Is it because the jQuery kicks at the end of the page loading and the charset metadata don't see the new text?

If it is that, how do I solve it?

Comment: tried with lang="sv" ? regards

Comment: you code seems working fine:-https://jsfiddle.net/2ayr2pvv/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.
I changed the lang attribute but there were no changes at all.
The page is a SharePoint page so the major part of the page is rendered on the server before to get sent to the browser. I don't know it that has something to do with the problem.